# How to distinguish and reward good posts on obscure topics

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I've started several threads on SO about "Windows Identity Foundation" because I've been programming with WIF for some time.  Oftentimes, I end up answering my own question months after I make my original post and with 0 votes.

Other times, I do get an answer and I'm the only one who votes it up, so the poster receives only 25 rep for a great answer.

It would be nice if there were some way I could distinguish good answers to my [unpopular] questions.  How could we do this without opening up the system to abuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any friends or colleagues who are using the same technology? Encourage them to come to Stack Overflow and participate on those specific tags as well.

You might email them a link to the tag page directly, like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wif

Comment: Hey, I know! Maybe you could set up some system where you get points for referring new users!

Comment: Yes, I have some friends in Russia who I am sure would like to sign up for SO and ask "What is your favorite thing about Visual Studio?"

Answer (score 6):

If you have the rep, set a bounty on it. You can award up to 500 points that way -- and it doesn't even have to be your own question.

Comment: In addition, consider that giving the bounty gives the question up to 7 days of limelight in the Featured tab - meaning you might be able to score that good answerer some upvotes by the increased visibility.

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't get that much rep in the first place from these questions and answers...  Time to become an expert on something else, I suppose.